# Java Lambda Stream List<User> to Map<Role, List<User>>

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have to write a method which takes a `List<User>` and returns a `Map<Role,List<User>>`.

`User` contains a `Person` instance, which contains a `Role`.
I must create a map where Role key is mapped to a list of users (where user has this Role).

I tried the following :

```
public static Map<Role, List<User>> groupUsersByRole(List<User> users) {
    users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap((u -> u.getPersonDetails().getRole()), users.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()  ) )
    users.stream().map(user -> user).filter(u -> u.).collect(Collectors.toList()) );
    //users.stream().filter(u -> u.getPersonDetails().getRole().getName().equals(u.getPersonDetails().getRole().getName())).map(user -> user.getName()).
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you really _have_ to use lambdas for that? Good old fashioned code will work and will be more legible...

Comment: @fge I disagree, `groupingBy` is largely more readable than the code you would write before Java 8..

Comment: I must use lambda and stream ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `Collectors.groupingBy`, which groups the elements of the Stream by a specified property :

```
Map<Role, List<User>> map = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u->u.getPersonDetails().getRole()));
```